What is EKS Managed Node Group Module?
I was looking into EKS Managed Node Group Module documentations, and found out that there is a eks_managed_node_groups in the AWS EKS Terraform module. And there is a submodule called EKS Managed Node Group Module.
Can someone explain to me the differences between these two managed node groups?
I tried deploying to AWS and I have two EC2 instances. One is from the AWS EKS Terraform module managed node group and another EKS Managed Node Group Module node group. I am very confused..

Terraform might look like this:
    module "eks_managed_node_group" {
    source          = "terraform-aws- 
    modules/eks/aws//modules/node_groups"
    cluster_name    = "my-eks-cluster"
    cluster_version = "1.21"
    subnets         = ["subnet-12345678", "subnet-87654321"]

    node_groups = {
        my_node_group = {
        desired_capacity = 2
        max_capacity     = 5
        min_capacity     = 1

        instance_type = "m5.large"

        key_name             = "my-key"
        additional_userdata  = "echo foo bar"
        additional_tags = {
        Name = "eks-node-group"
      }
    }
  }
}


Thanks for answering, but it didn't really clear my questions. Do you know why the official example Terraform code define managed node groups twice? Here: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/15a3248f595dd25c5e883e858322ba91e30ffc82/examples/eks_managed_node_group/main.tf#L73-L87 and here: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/15a3248f595dd25c5e883e858322ba91e30ffc82/examples/eks_managed_node_group/main.tf#L354
